# Тире или запятая в диктанте?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, тире

И снова возвращаюсь к тотальному диктанту.

Якоб Иванович настолько привык произносить одни и те же слова и зачитывать одни и те же задачки, что научился при этом мысленно раздваиваться внутри своего тела: язык его бормотал текст очередного грамматического правила, рука зажатой в ней линейкой вяло шлёпала по затылку чересчур говорливого ученика, ноги степенно несли тело по классу — **от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно —** туда-сюда.

> Какой знак препинания вы поставите вместо второго тире? В диктанте — запятая. Второе тире посчитали за
>   ошибку.

Answer (score 4):

Из предложенных вариантов мне больше нравится следующий:

...несли тело (1) по классу (2) от кафедры к задней стене, (3) затем обратно — (4) туда-сюда.

Между обстоятельствами 2 и 3 **однородные** отношения (перечислительная интонация), между 1 и (2 + 3) — **неоднородные**, обстоятельство 4 **обобщает**  (2 + 3) или **поясняет** в присоединительной конструкции (то есть ***туда-сюда***)

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) Заданный вариант:

....ноги степенно несли тело по классу от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно — туда-сюда.

2) Вариант без последнего обстоятельства:

....ноги степенно несли тело по классу — от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно.

Comment: Слово класс вступает в однородные отношения словом кафедра? На мой взгляд, класс - обобщающее слово.

Comment: Однородные отношения между двумя направлениями (в классе): от кафедры к стене, от стены к кафедре. "В классе"  - это обстоятельство  места (где?) , направления неоднородны по отношению к нему, так как отвечают на вопрос (куда?), но между собой они однородны.

Comment: А как вы прокомментируете отсутствие знака препинания после слова " класс" или постановку тире после него?

Comment: Хотя направления движения неоднородны по отношению к "классу", мы могли бы  оформить эти обстоятельства как присоединительные и поставить тире. Это было бы правильно и вполне логично  при отсутствии последнего обстоятельства "туда-сюда", но именно оно мешает это сделать, так как два разных тире нежелательны.

Comment: @Jasmin Извините, я совершенно запуталась в 1-2-3-4! Не могли бы Вы привести концовку предложения - с теми знаками, о которых Вы говорите.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение к ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь тот самый случай, когда правило "от второго тире надо избавляться" вполне действует. Понятно, что второе тире тут стоит не как парное к первому, а как знак интонационный, перед уточнением кл всей конструкции, но и само по себе  этот тире здесь совершенно не добавляет понимания фразе, только путает.

Кроме запятой вариантов не вижу.

Comment: Некоторые варианты я вообще не понимаю. Самый приемлемый вариант( если считать постановку двух тире ошибкой) является двоеточие и тире.

Answer (score 1):

Сами они комментируют так.

Между однородными членами предложения, которые соединены  между собой бессоюзной связью ставится запятая. В этом случае допустима постановка тире, если рассматривать выражение туда-суда как обобщающее слово к предшествующему ряду однородных членов **от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно** В предложении возможна только одно непарное тире, в предшествующих позициях знака тире быть не должно. Постановка **двоеточия** считается ошибкой, так как двоеточие ставится **после** обобщающего слова **перед** рядом однородных членов, здесь же оно стоит после ряда однородных обстоятельств места.

Допустимые варианты.

несли тело по классу от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно — туда,сюда.

несли тело по классу от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно — туда-сюда.

несли тело по классу, от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно — туда,сюда.

несли тело по классу от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно — туда-сюда.

несли тело по классу: от кафедры к задней стене, затем обратно — туда-сюда.